# Variar print según condición en python

Tags: python

tengo este código donde el print debe variar según la condición. Primero, debo verificar con "código" todos los strings de lista, verificando todas las opciones para la variable (código representa el primer caracter de la lista). Si código concuerda con el primer caracter imprime x texto, pero si no, imprime otra cosa. Este es mi código actualmente:

```
def listarDonadoresTotales():
    lista = ["3035", "1011", "4987", "293456", "12875", "5234", "129" \
        , "2654", "2321", "181", "170", "6870", "870", "93"]
    codigo = 1
    while codigo < 10:
        i = 0
        while i < len(lista):
            iLista = lista[i]
            x = iLista[0]
            if x == str(codigo):
                print('Registrado')
            else:
                print('No registrado')
            i += i
        codigo += 1
```

Como nota, la variable codigo puede ser cualquier valor de 0 a 9. Cuando codigo sea por ejemplo 7, deber imprimir "no registrado" ya que ningun valor de la lista inicia por 7, todos los demas deberian imprimir "registrado", pero la salida solo repite "no registrado" infinitamente. Debo usar listas y procesos iterativos para hacer la función.
Gracias por la ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El código que propones es C escrito en Python. La solución Python es:

```
def listarDonadoresTotales():
    lista = ["3035", "1011", "4987", "293456", "12875", "5234", "129" \
        , "2654", "2321", "181", "170", "6870", "870", "93"]
    listita = set(int(cod[0]) for cod in lista)
    for codigo in range(10):
        if codigo in listita:
            print(f'{codigo} registrado')
        else:
            print(f'{codigo} no registrado')
```

Lo primero es que necesito comparar contra el primer digito de cada código en la lista. No puedo comparar un entero contra un string; lo mejor es extraer el primer digito del string y convertirlo a entero para hacer la comparación. Como hay que hacerlo 10 veces, mejor preparo una versión acotada de los primeros digitos. Podría ser una lista, pero tendría repeticiones; mejor hago un `set`, que elimina automáticamente todos los duplicados.

Usaremos una expresión *generadora*, que es como una comprensión de listas sin lo `[]`, para alimentar directamente la función `set()`, que toma un iterable y genera un conjunto descartando los duplicados:

```
listita = set(int(cod[0]) for cod in lista) => {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9}
```

En Python no se hace la iteración a mano; se usa un `for` para recorrer los valores de 0 a 9:

```
for codigo in range(10):
```

Tampoco necesito iterar sobre la lista/set para ver si contiene un valor determinado. Esto es Python y simplemente usas la condición `in`:

```
if codigo in listita:
```

Si la condición se cumple, imprimimos un mensaje; si no, imprimimos otro.

#### Demo

```
listarDonadoresTotales()
```

produce:

```
0 no registrado
1 registrado
2 registrado
3 registrado
4 registrado
5 registrado
6 registrado
7 no registrado
8 registrado
9 registrado

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto, sin embargo por más que quiera no puedo usar set(), solo puedo usar lista y procesos iterativos. Hay alguna forma de sustituirlo?

Comment: Puedes escribir "list" en lugar de "set" y funciona lo mismo. Si te piden usar iteraciones, lo más probable es que tu profesor no sepa Python.

Comment: Perfecto, voy a intentar eso, muchas gracias! Y si, todos en la clase estamos convencidos de que no es la mejor manera de aprender python

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no estás cambiando `i` dentro del loop, así que termina repitiéndose infinitamente:

```py
i += i # 0+=0
```

Adicionalmente, estás recorriendo todos los elementos de la lista cuando solo te preocupa el primero, terminas repitiendo "Registrado/No registrado" varias veces.

Comment: Qué debería modificar para que no se repita más de lo necesario?

Comment: @SAMG23 Si solo te interesa el primer dígito, el segundo `while` no es necesario.

Comment: Por alguna razón seguía repitiendo no registrado luego de eso. Y solo con el código 9 imprimía registrado, no sé a qué se deba